# Is there any possibility that gender is determined by Temperature?

Tags: reproduction, gender

One day I was watching TV show. It was based on Fire Dragon. They stated that if the dragon provide greater warmth to the egg, then a male Dragon will hatch. And if the Dragon provide less warmth to the egg it will be female Dragon. 
This was totally Science Fiction!!

But is there any possibility that, the *Temperature* decides the Gender of progeny.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but the answer to this question is in the background of the linked question.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely more than science fiction. Many species have sex determination that depend upon the temperature.

As a rule of thumb, when it comes to sex, not much has been invented in fictions. The diversity of reproductive system is HUGE! I will not mention 1% of the existing complexity in sex systems. For simplicity, below I will limit my concepts and examples to big animals only. I won't talk about

- double fertilization
- cloning
- parthenogenesis
- dosage compensation
- Mating types
- Cases of multinucleated cells typically in fungi but not only
- Asexual reproduction
- Systems with more that two genders or with coexisting hermaphrodite along with a single other gender
- Liability factor
- Reaction norms for sex determination
- How reproduction relate to all that
- How dosage compensation relate to all that
- How the concept of individual relate to all that
- etc...

**Sex Determination System: GSD vs ESD**

There is a great diversity of sex determination system. The standard is to classify them in two

- Environment Sec Determation (ESD)
- Genetic Sec Determation (GSD)

Of course, the reality is more complex. In many species a mixture of both genetics and environment clues matter.

Within ESD species, there is quite a bit of variety. Some species use temperature (e.g. crocodiles, Nile tilapia, Australian skink lizard), others use social cues (e.g. clownfish, swordfish, boa constrictor).

Within GSD, there is also a great deal of diversity. By far not all species use the XY system used in mammals.

**Related post**

- [**Do males of all sexual species have Y chromosomes?**](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27511/do-males-of-all-sexual-species-have-y-chromosomes)
- [**Have there been any theories put forward as to the reasons behind Temperature-Dependant Sex Determination in reptiles?**](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17233/have-there-been-any-theories-put-forward-as-to-the-reasons-behind-temperature-de)